# Using JS to download PDF from URL results in 0k file

Tags: javascript

I have been using Javascript to download PDF from a URL. It was working until earlier this week.

Here is my code:

```
if (file !== ''){
            ticket.log.action('Try URL - ' + file);
            //Name of the download file
            var fnameURL = file.slice(file.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            //Local file path of the download file
            var LocalFile = Temp + "/" + fnameURL;
            var connection = new URL(file).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0");
            //if (connection) {
                var targetFile = new File(LocalFile);
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(connection.getInputStream(), targetFile);
            //}
```

Nothing changed since last week. Any suggestions?

Comment: If nothing changed from your side, then it must be changed from the server side, and please share the url you are trying to download

Comment: Have you tried to copy the URL in the browser and see if there is the PDF displayed?

Comment: I can copy the URL into the browser and it downloads the PDF.

Comment: Here is one of the URLs.

http://printpoint.comgraphics.com/downloads/6267091103526/100684-CLG91050ST_6x6_v4_3.20_Print.pdf

Comment: Found that the supplied URL was written as //http instead of //https causing this issue with the JS. Thank you for your input.